# What are these magnetic connectors called?

Tags: connector, magnet

For a project, I am looking for a specific kind of magnetic connector. You can often find those on Apple products. It usually looks something like this:

[AliExpress Magnetic Connector](https://de.aliexpress.com/item/33049945641.html?spm=a2g0o.detail.1000060.1.1d052d75b5KioF&gps-id=pcDetailBottomMoreThisSeller&scm=1007.13339.146401.0&scm_id=1007.13339.146401.0&scm-url=1007.13339.146401.0&pvid=6b3efd74-195f-44ab-9f55-4e436f9e2c7a&_t=gps-id:pcDetailBottomMoreThisSeller,scm-url:1007.13339.146401.0,pvid:6b3efd74-195f-44ab-9f55-4e436f9e2c7a,tpp_buckets:668%230%23131923%2358_668%23808%237756%23230_668%23888%233325%237_668%232846%238115%23854_668%232717%237565%23702__668%233468%2315607%2347)
[image]

The little pins are spring loaded I guess. The search for 'magnetic spring connector' seemed promising at first, but I still did not find much.
Does anyone know what these are called exactly or have a link to Digikey or Mouser?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=Magnetic+Connector&client=firefox-b-d&sxsrf=ALeKk0240a0RHuVWRQUv2pqBBeQIuggldw:1595629811916&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiIhYeh-ObqAhXihXIEHWZAD_kQ_AUoAXoECDQQAw&biw=816&bih=802 What no specs?

Comment: the ali express page you linked names them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're called several different things:

- Magnetic **Compression Contact**
- **Spring-loaded** Magnetic Connector
- Magnetic **Pogo Pin** Connector

Some examples I found are [Adam Tech](http://adam-tech.com/products_1.php?bgid=68), [CLE](https://www.cletk.com/connectors/magnetic-connector), or [Hytepro](http://www.magnetconnector.com/).